# Tomcat authentication and operations for the user

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to get a better understading on how Tomcat handles the login operations. My course's lesson on this topic was pretty lackluster so I'm having lots of doubts.

1) Suppose that I want to create a login for a site, and that I'm storing the credentials on a mySQL database. In order to configure Tomcat to use the database there's tutorials on the internet so that's "easy". What is not clear to me is how the authentication is actually handled.

Is it 100% handeld by Tomcat? This is what I've come to understand. Basically in my form I will use two textfields named j_username and j_password. This way Tomcat, once it looks at the HTTP request, it will notice those two fields, and it will automatically check if the username/password combo matches anything in the database, and if it does it will let the client who made the request access the page it wants (page protection is done by using the tag  in the deployment descriptor, where you specify the pages you want to protect, and which users roles can access them).

So if my protected resource (be it a servlet or a JSP) receives a request, I am 100% sure that it was made by an user who went through Tomcat and was found to have the right privileges to access the page. So, inside the servlet, I don't have to analyze the request in order to get the user's username/password, check them by hand in my database and then if I find a match let the servlet continue. It was already done by Tomcat, right?

2) If 1 is correct, how do I handle dynamic contents for the page that was accessed?
Say that in this protected page I want to show a list of cars owned by the user who logged in.

To find her cars, I need to look in the database. But how do I do that? I will need at least some data to base my query on, like the username. 
I looked through HTTPServletRequest documentation and I found the getRemoteUser() method: Returns the login of the user making this request, if the user has been authenticated, or null if the user has not been authenticated.

Can I just use it to retrieve the username, plug it into my query and search for it in the database? And also use it to execute other operations, like show a "Welcome back username!" like at the top of my page and such things?

Seems easy enough, and that's throwing me off a little, ahah.

Also, how is session handled? Is it handled by Tomcat or do I have to do something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. ... Basically in my form I will use two textfields named j_username and j_password. This way Tomcat, once it looks at the HTTP request, it will notice those two fields, and it will automatically check if the username/password combo matches anything in the database, and if it does it will let the client who made the request access the page it wants (page protection is done by using the tag in the deployment descriptor, where you specify the pages you want to protect, and which users roles can access them).

This is all true *provided* the login form is posted to `/j_security_check`.

> So if my protected resource (be it a servlet or a JSP) receives a request, I am 100% sure that it was made by an user who went through Tomcat and was found to have the right privileges to access the page. So, inside the servlet, I don't have to analyze the request in order to get the user's username/password, check them by hand in my database and then if I find a match let the servlet continue. It was already done by Tomcat, right?

Right.

> 2) ... I found the `getRemoteUser()` method: 'Returns the login of the user making this request, if the user has been authenticated, or null if the user has not been authenticated.' Can I just use it to retrieve the username, plug it into my query and search for it in the database?

Yes. It contains the same thing that `j_username` contained in the login form.

> And also use it to execute other operations, like show a "Welcome back username!" like at the top of my page and such things?

Sure.

> Also, how is session handled? Is it handled by Tomcat

Yes.

> or do I have to do something more?

Not unless you want to: for example, change its expiry time from the default. Or invalidate it or log the user out, of course.